# defining inline functions under template class definition

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to make an inline definition of a template class ctor under the class definition (I know you can do it inside, but I prefer to do it outside in the header file). However, MSVC is telling me that `Matrix` requires a template argument list in the ctor definition... I can easily solve this by defining the function inside the class (it still will be inlined), but I would prefer to do it outside due to esthetic reasons. Is there a way to solve this?

```
// .hpp 

#pragma once

template <typename T, size_t rows, size_t cols>
class Matrix {
private:
    constexpr size_t m_size = rows * cols;
    std::array<T, m_size> m_arr;
public:
    __forceinline Matrix();
};

Matrix::Matrix() : m_arr() { // this gives errors
    // do ctor stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, MSVC is telling me that Matrix requires a template argument list in the ctor definition...
>
> ```
> Matrix::Matrix() : m_arr() { // this gives errors
> ```

You missed the template specification that should be given for the definition, that's probably what the compiler message tells you:

```
template <typename T, size_t rows, size_t cols> // <<<< This!
Matrix<T,rows,cols>::Matrix() : m_arr() { 
   // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ... and this
    // do ctor stuff
}
```

---

> ... but I prefer to do it outside in the header file ...

To do so put the definition into a file that isn't atomatically picked up as a translation unit by your build system (e.g. some extension like `.icc` or `.tcc`), and `#include` that one at the end of your header containing the template class declarations.

The complete code should look like

**`Matrix.hpp`**

```
#pragma once
#include <cstddef>

template <typename T, std::size_t rows, std::size_t cols>
class Matrix {
private:
    constexpr static std::size_t m_size = rows * cols;
    std::array<T, m_size> m_arr;
public:
    __forceinline Matrix();
};

#include "Matrix.icc"
```

**`Matrix.icc`**

```
template <typename T, std::size_t rows, std::size_t cols>
Matrix<T,rows,cols>::Matrix() : m_arr() { 
    // do ctor stuff
}
```